# Quando um argumento padrão é avaliado no Python?

Tags: python, argumento, python-internals

Consideremos a seguinte classe:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, values = []):
        self.values = values
```

Vale notar que estamos utilizando um atributo de instância e não um atributo de classe, porém, vejam o seguinte código:

```
a = Foo()
b = Foo()
```

Duas instâncias distintas, mas ao alterar o atributo de uma das instâncias:

```
a.values.append(1)
```

O atributo da outra instância é alterado:

```
print(b.values) # [1]
```

> Vejam funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/JMwxE6).

Ao verificar o `id` de cada atributo, é possível verificar que ambos representam o mesmo objeto, um comportamento esperado para um atributo de classe, não de instância:

```
print(id(a.values)) # 47568867296648
print(id(b.values)) # 47568867296648
```

Obviamente que esse é o comportamento somente quando o valor padrão do atributo é um tipo mutável, mas mesmo assim parece ser um comportamento estranho.

Esse comportamento deveria ser esperado e por quê ocorre?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Espera-se que uma chamada de função crie novos objetos para valores padrão, mas isso não é o que acontece. Os valores padrão são criados apenas uma vez, **quando a função é definida**.

Se esse objeto for alterado, como a lista, neste exemplo, as chamadas subsequentes para a função se referirão a este objeto alterado.

Por definição, objetos **imutáveis**, como `números`, `strings`, `tuplas` e o `None`, estão protegidos contra mudanças. Alterações em objetos mutáveis, como dicionários, listas e instâncias de classe, podem levar à confusão.

Por causa desse recurso, é recomendado não fazer uso de objetos mutáveis como valores padrão, em vez disso use `None` *como o valor padrão* e dentro de uma função ou método verifique com `is None` e, caso seja `None`, crie um novo objeto mutável (como dicionário, lista, etc) dentro da condição (`if`).

No seu script o **argumento** `value = []` dentro do método é **compartilhado** com todos as instâncias, pois o objeto mutável `[]` é criado apenas uma vez (no momento de declarar a classe) e as instâncias irão obter os dados dela, conforme a documentação:

> https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-are-default-values-shared-between-objects

Então creio que possa usar `None` e fazer uma checagem com Python:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, values = None):
        if values is None:
            self.values = [] # cria uma lista vazia
        else:
            self.values = values # cria uma lista vazia

>>> d = Foo()
>>> e = Foo()
>>> d.values.append(1)
>>> d.values.append(2)
>>> e.values
[]
```

Comment: Float é um tipo mutável ou imutável em Python? Acontece isto com floats também?

Comment: Muito útil esta dica: "é recomendado não fazer uso de objetos mutáveis como valores padrão nas definições de funções, usar None no lugar e tratar dentro da função".

Comment: Boa noite caro @ThiagoKrempser, números se refere ao float e aos inteiros, também são imutáveis. Obrigado pela edição, foi uma ótima contribuição.

Answer (score 3):

Complementando a [resposta do Guilherme](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/240667/5878), de fato, o que ocorre é a avaliação dos argumentos em tempo de definição do método e como os objetos em Python são tratados como referência, na definição do método é criado um objeto que representa o valor padrão e em cada nova instância (ou chamada do método), o parâmetro apontará para essa mesma instância. Isso explica o porquê do retorno de `id` é o mesmo para as diferentes instâncias e fica ainda mais claro quando analisado o atributo `__defaults__` do método.

De acordo com a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html), o atributo `__defaults__` é uma tupla que contém os valores padrões dos argumentos de uma função ou método. Neste caso, considerando o código apresentado na pergunta:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, values = []):
        self.values = values
```

Podemos verificar o valor de `__defaults__` do método inicializador:

```
print(Foo.__init__.__defaults__) # ([],)
```

O primeiro valor desta tupla é um objeto mutável que representa o valor padrão do argumento `values`, existindo desde a definição da classe, visto que, no Python, a própria classe é um objeto - e o método também é um objeto.

Ao verificar o retorno de `id` deste objeto é confirmado que este representa a mesma referência de `a.values` e `b.values`:

```
print(id(Foo.__init__.__defaults__[0])) # 47568867296648
```

Para confirmar tudo o que foi dito na prática, basta verificar o valor em `__defaults__` após uma instância de `Foo` que possui seu atributo de classe modificado:

```
print(Foo.__init__.__defaults__) # ([],)

a = Foo()
a.values.append(1)

print(Foo.__init__.__defaults__) # ([1],)
```

Isto é, ao criar uma instância e modificar o atributo de instância desta, sendo este atributo do tipo mutável, o próprio objeto que representa o valor padrão do argumento, armazenado em `__defaults__`, é modificado de igual forma.

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/aSD3mV).

Uma pergunta semelhante a esta foi feita no Stack Overflow:

[Why are default arguments evaluated at definition time in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1651154/1452488)