# Construtor python com **kwargs

Tags: python, python-3.x

Gostaria se saber se o uso do **kwargs em um construtor é a melhor alternativa ou se existe um caminho mais indicado para casos semelhantes ao exposto abaixo:

```
   class Duvida(object):

       def __init__(self, **kwargs):

           self.formato=''
           self.nota='5'

           if 'formato' in kwargs.keys():
               self.formato=kwargs['formato']
           if 'nota' in kwargs.keys():
               self.nota=kwargs['nota']


   q=Duvida(formato='Formato Personalizado')
```

Comment: Não, pois [*explicit is better than implicit*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). Se quer receber parâmetros no construtor, especifique-os.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A melhor forma é declarar explicitamente os argumentos. Citando a [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> *Explicit is better than implicit*

Neste caso, caso queira deixar os parâmetros como opcionais, basta inicializá-los com um valor padrão:

```
class Duvida(objet):
    def __init__(self, formato=None, nota=None):
        self.formato = formato if formato is not None else ''
        self.nota = nota if nota is not None else '5'

duvida = Duvida(formato='Formato Personalizado')
```

Isso evita o problema de inicializar os parâmetros com tipos mutáveis, tal como lista.

[Quando um argumento padrão é avaliado no Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/240652/5878)

Mas se os seus valores são imutáveis, inicializá-los com o próprio valor não deverá gerar nenhum efeito colateral no programa:

```
class Duvida(objet):
    def __init__(self, formato='', nota='5'):
        self.formato = formato
        self.nota = nota

duvida = Duvida(formato='Formato Personalizado')
```

Use apenas `*args` e `**kwargs` quando não conhecer previamente os parâmetros.

Comment: Perfeito. Obrigrado!