# Problemas ao iniciar métodos numa classe python?

Tags: python, classes

Sou novo no python e comecei com classes agora, tentei iniciar uma classe
mas por algum motivo sempre dá erro, o erro muda mas sempre dá, no momento estou com o código desta forma :

```
class Inimigo:

    def __init__(self, vida):
        self.vida = vida 


    def ataque(self):
        self.vida -= 2


    inimigo1 = Inimigo()
```

No entanto o erro que retorna é :

```
__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'vida'
```

Não entendo, utilizar o self.vida = vida já não inicializa vida? E outra se eu quiser que vida comece como um valor definido como devo fazer?

```
self.vida = vida = 10
```

ou

```
def __init__(self, vida = 10):
    self.vida = vida
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você tem a classe:

```
class Inimigo:

    def __init__(self, vida):
        self.vida = vida 


    def ataque(self):
        self.vida -= 2


inimigo1 = Inimigo()
```

No inicializador da classe, você possui um parâmetro `vida`, que será o valor de `self.vida`. Porém, na hora de instanciar a classe, você não passa nenhum valor. Se você não definir, qual deveria ser o valor de `vida`?

Neste caso, o que você precisará fazer é:

```
inimigo = Inimigo(10)
```

Assim, `vida` receberá o valor 10 e, portanto, `self.vida` será 10.

Perceba que Python permite você definir parâmetros nomeados, o que em alguns momentos deixa o código muito mais legível. Por exemplo:

```
inimigo = Inimigo(vida=10)
```

Ficando claro que 10 é a vida, não o poder de ataque, por exemplo.

Caso não queira definir sempre um valor, você pode definir um valor padrão para o parâmetro, assim como fez no final da sua pergunta:

```
def __init__(self, vida=10):
    self.vida = vida
```

Assim, mesmo que você faça:

```
inimigo = Inimigo()
```

O valor de `self.vida` será 10.

Um cuidado que você deve tomar é o valor padrão do parâmetro será avaliado na definição da classe, então evite, a menos que faça sentido, utilizar tipos mutáveis como valores padrões nos parâmetros.

**Leituras**

- [Quando um argumento padrão é avaliado no Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/240652/5878)
- [Qual a diferença entre parâmetro e argumento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/5878)