# É possível chamar um setter dentro de um método da própria classe em python?

Tags: python

Tenho uma classe que lê um arquivo XML e com as informações do arquivo preenche os atributos da classe. Todas as verificações de consistência de dados eu faço dentro dos "setters" dos atributos (a classe pode ser usada sem o arquivo de entrada, diretamente por outro código e assim não preciso repetir as verificações em outras partes do código).

Por exemplo, tenho o setter:

```
 @fluid_list.setter
    def fluid_list(self, fluid_list: []):
        for i in fluid_list:
            self.__fluid_list.append(fluid_list[i].upper())
        assert (len(fluid_list) == len(set(fluid_list)))
        assert (len(np.setdiff1d(fluid_list,["OIL", "WATER", "GAS"])) == 0)
```

E tenho o método

```
def read_file(self):

        try:

            # parse an xml file by name
            mydoc = minidom.parse(self.__input_file_name)


            # reads function elements to get all function names (FunctionList)
            list_elem = mydoc.getElementsByTagName('fluid')  
            fluid_l = []
            for elem in list_elem:
                fluid_l.append(elem.firstChild.data)
            self.fluid_list(fluid_l)    
            print(self.__fluid_list)


        except Exception as e:
            logger.catch_error(e)
```

Ao executar eu recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
File "...prj\InputData.py", line 158, in read_file self.fluid_list(fluid_l)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Existe alguma maneira de chamar o setter dentro da classe, ou preciso incluir a verificação de consistência no método que lê o arquivo de entrada?

Comment: `self.fluid_list(fluid_l)`, isso deveria ser `self.fluid_list = fluid_l` se a intenção é chamar o *setter* da sua propriedade.

Comment: E fazer o parâmetro `fluid_list: []` parece não fazer sentido. Neste caso o `[]` será uma anotação de tipo e não faria muito sentido ser `[]`. Se a ideia era definir um valor padrão, deveria ser `fluid_list = []`, mas mesmo assim precisará tomar muito cuidado com [Quando um argumento padrão é avaliado no Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/240652/5878)

Comment: Sim, é essa a intenção e funcionou perfeitamente. Minha primeira implementação foi desta maneira, mas devia ter algo errado em outra parte do código pois não tinha funcionado... Muito obrigada!