# uniao de listas

Tags: python

To fazendo esse algoritmo onde tenho que fazer a união de duas listas sendo que os numeros repetidos só podem aparecer uma vez. Mas ta dando errado, alguém para me salvar?

```
def uniao(l1,l2,r=[]):
    if len(l1) == 0:
            return r
        else:
            if l1[0] in r and l1[0] not in l2:
                return uniao(l1[1:],l2,r)
            else:
                return uniao(l1[1:],l2,r + [l1[0]]+[l2[0]])
```

Comment: Como verificou que está dando errado? Que teste fez? Qual foi o resultado obtido e qual era o esperado? Aliás, cuidado ao definir um objeto mutável como valor padrão de um parâmetro, como a lista (leia mais em [Quando um argumento padrão é avaliado no Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/240652/5878)). Aliás, revise a indentação do seu código na pergunta; não temos como saber se isso está errado no código ou se foi só erro de formatação aqui na pergunta.

Comment: Era para aparecer como resultado [1,2,3,5], porém aparece [1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1]

Comment: Bom, depende das listas de entrada para isso... Tente fazer o [teste de mesa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/220474/5878) do seu código.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi, você ta fazendo um uma função que verifica os dados de dois array's e adiciona no primeiro oque tem no segundo mas não tem no primeiro.

Se isso estiver correto, segue o código:

```
def uniao (l1,l2):
    r = []
    for a in l1:
        r.append(a)
    for i in l2:
        if i in r:
            pass
        else:
            r.append(i)
    return r

l1 = [1,2,3,4]
l2 = [4,5,6,7]

print(uniao(l1,l2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar

```
def uniao(l1,l2):
    return list(set(l1+l2))
```

Neste caso, você junta as duas listas, faz um set() neles (o que fará com tenha apenas valores únicos, porém no formato {}) e então passar para dentro de uma lista.
Você tem os valores únicos das duas listas.

Como você pode ver [neste link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-set-method/), a função set() pega os valores únicos e já deixa ordenado (se tiver uma lista embaralhada de valores).

**EDITADO:**

Você também pode fazer uma função que pode receber uma maior variedade de listas, passando a função com argumento *args e iterar por ele como no exemplo abaixo:

```
def uniao(*arg):
    return list(set([j for i in arg for j in i]))
```

Por exemplo:

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [1,2,5]
l3 = [1,2,3,4]
print(uniao(l1,l2,l3))

>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Assim, você pode passar o número de listas que quiser, lembrando que este não irá funcionar caso passe um número.

Para que possa ser utilizado algo que não seja uma lista, também pode fazer o código da seguinte maneira:

```
def uniao(*arg):
    lista = []
    for i in arg:
        if type(i) == list:
            for j in i:
                lista.append(j)
        else:
            lista.append(i)
    return list(set(lista))

l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [1,2,5]
l3 = [1,2,3,4]
l4 = 6

print(uniao2(l1,l2,l3,l4))

>>  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Seria possível fazer essa função uniao sem as funções integradas???

Comment: Poderia ser mais específico?